# DB Browser for SQLite - Error Uploading CSV

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv, db-browser-sqlite

I am trying to upload a csv to DB Browser for SQLite on my Macbook. I properly uploaded one table into my database, but the other two give me the same error:

`Error importing data from record number 609. Inserting row failed: not an error`

For both files, it shots the record number from the last line of the data.

Here's what I have tried:

- Downloaded the newest version 3.11.2 of DB Browser for SQLite
- Used the Import Feature - Table from CSV under the File Tab
- Checked a primary key and left it unchecked
- Checked the desired 'Not Null' values and left them unchecked

I am considering trying to import the csv from the command line into the table. My command line skills are not super strong, but I have been searching these forums to get advice.

Thank  you for the help!

Comment: Looking at this comment: https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/1714#issuecomment-456132426 Have you tried removing headers from the tables before uploading?

Comment: Thank you for that link! Removing the headings did the trick! Many thanks!